# gstreamer needs g_main_loop_run while gtk needs gtk_main()

Tags: c, gtk, gstreamer

I'm trying to write a GTK+ application in C that uses gstreamer.

GTK+ needs `gtk_main()` to execute.

gstreamer needs `g_main_loop_run()` to execute.

Both of them stall the execution flow.

What can I do that `gtk_main()` will also hold the `GMainLoop` that I created for gstreamer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not create a `GMainLoop`, `gtk_main()` internally creates one already which should suffice for any `glib` based library that uses events/signals.

See [this question which quotes the `gtk_main()` source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575750/how-does-gtk-work)

Answer (score 1):

Likewise gtk can use the GMainLoop created by g_main_loop_new() as long as the default context is used (NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at that tutorial for a simple C example of GTK and GStreamer in C.

[Guitar Tuner in C](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/guitar-tuner.c.html.en)